# Bypass Prompt of Python script

Tags: python

There is a weblogic script test.sh which has the below code.

```
echo "Starting   ...."
java weblogic.WLST helloworld.py
echo "Ending ..."
```

The output after printing "Starting ...." prompts for the below msg

> Creating the key file can reduce the security of your system if it is
>   not kept in a secured location after it is created. Do you want to
>   create the key file? y or n

Then I have to manually press y or n which I wish to automate as 'y'.

This I am excepting the no user intervention should be required.

I need to somehow automatically pass 'y' so that the script continues flow and not stop for user input.

Below are the contents of the helloworld.py script

```
connect(user1,p@ss,'t3://myhost:9999')
storeUserConfig(userConfigFile='userconfig.secure',userKeyFile='userkey.secure') 
disconnect() 
exit()
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: What's in helloworld.py?  What are you actually doing here?  There's hardly any information in this question.

Comment: If this is Linux and Bash you can do `echo 'y' | java weblogic.WLST helloworld.py`, but I believe you should retag your question if that is the case.

Comment: Rephrased my Question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Control from Unix shell -> Python -> & back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268745/need-control-from-unix-shell-python-back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered here -> [Need Control from Unix shell -> Python -> & back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268745/need-control-from-unix-shell-python-back)

The solution is subprocess() in python.