# Need Control from Unix shell -> Python -> & back

Tags: python, unix, wlst

There is a weblogic script test.sh which has the below code.

```
echo "Starting   ...."
java weblogic.WLST helloworld.py
echo "Ending ..."The output after printing "Starting ...."
```

The second line of code prompts for the below msg

> Creating the key file can reduce the security of your system if it is
>   not kept in a secured location after it is created. Do you want to
>   create the key file? y or n

Then I have to manually press y or n which I wish to automate as 'y'.

This I am excepting with no user intervention be required.

I need to somehow automatically pass 'y' so that the script continues flow and not stop for user input.

Below are the contents of the helloworld.py script

```
connect(user1,p@ss,'t3://myhost:9999')
storeUserConfig(userConfigFile='userconfig.secure',userKeyFile='userkey.secure') 
disconnect() 
exit()
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: What exactly can we help you with?

Comment: Mentioned in the OP: need to somehow automatically pass 'y' so that the script continues flow and not stop for user input and thus the control should automatically come back to the unix shell post executing the python which is not happening in the current case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the `java weblogic.WLST helloworld.py` command as a subprocess in python. Then you can parse the output for the mentioned question and enter the 'y' via `stdin.write('y\n')`.

Comment: The need is to trigger the python from unix shell, so will your solution work ? I am not sure exactly how to achieve what you suggested

Comment: No problem. I meant create a second python file which calls the `helloworld.py` script as subprocess. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html for details about the subprocess module. The second script must then be called by weblogic instead of `helloworld.py`.

Comment: k... i tried two commands but both look problematic throwing errors. process=subprocess.call(['./helloworld.py', 'sys.argv[1]', 'sys.argv[2]']) output=process.stdin.write('y')               .....Error: Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/tmp/call_helloworld.py", line 5, in ?
NameError: subprocess

Comment: Did you `import subprocess`?

Comment: If i say "import subprocess"       then i get the below error.    ImportError: no module named subprocess

Comment: Then the WLST environment seems not to have the subprocess module. So my suggestion does not work. Maybe you can do the `java weblogic.WLST helloworld.py` invocation in a python script from the command line. So instead of running `test.sh` from commandline run a `test.py` from commandline where you do the subprocess call for WLST.